# Failed to deploy an application in jboss

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, jboss, boot

An error occurs while trying  to deploy an application in JBoss

`13:17:25,685 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "pcp-full.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" =>`

*Server is up but the application is not up*
**Please HELP**

Answer (score 0):

it looks like youre missing dependencies.